# FB login and privacy policy

Tags: authentication, facebook-application, privacy-policy

I'm bulding up a site, where the ONLY ONE method for log in, is the fb login button.

Now i'm wondering if i need to make users check and read the my own site's privacy and policy before and accept that is some way, is this needed?

The site is for text/pourpouse sharing, and you can only interact with the site after you are logged/registered, althought you can only navigate lists of users and pourpouses.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is if you're storing any information from users or not? I think if you're using FB you don't need to make users accept anything, but, generally when someone uses a site, they're agreeing to their terms, even if they don't accept anything literally.

So IMO you should be fine as long as your privacy policy is accessible easily for all users.

Comment: so i don't need to link to the privacy policy in fb registration cicle? i mean, if i let users login with fb then i add a link to the site footer for privacy and terms is ok for you?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Login serves the purpose of authentication.  It does not address the issue of the collection, storage, use and transmission of personal information.  If you have any user personal information, you should address it in a nice, readable privacy policy.

This includes what third parties do on your website.  Advertisers, data brokers - do they collect personal information through your site?  Please disclose all that.

And, there is a new California law that will be effective this summer: You must say how the site responds to a user's 'do not track" signals.  The FTC, the California Attorney General and other state attorney generals have been actively suing companies concerning this issue (not just concerning websites directed to children).